# Makefile ignores existing directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have Makefile:

```
MAKEFILE_DIR:=$(dir $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
DIR:=$(MAKEFILE_DIR)/some/where

.PHONY: load install

load: $(DIR)
  some-actions...

$(DIR): install
  another-actions...
```

when I run `make load` I see that `$(DIR)` is treated as missing and `$(DIR)` goal is called, so `install` is called and `another-actions` too. This happens each time. Where is the error? How to fix it so `$(DIR)` will be called only when it does not exist?

PS. I had idea that mtime of the `$(DIR)` changes, may be it's changing after each "make" run. I checked it with `stat`, seems it does not change.

Comment: I checked make behavior with `make -d` and seems it tests prerequisites (they are PHONY) of `$(DIR)` always even if it exists. Then make writes that `$(DIR)` deps were updated. Is it normal? I am confused

Answer (score 1):

Every `.PHONY` target is treated as if it **does not exist**. Therefore, it's **always rebuilt**. Every time any prerequisite is rebuilt, the target (in this case, $(DIR)) **IS ALSO REBUILT**.

> How to fix it

Either drop out `install` from `$(DIR)` (in fact, I dont' understand why `install` should be done **before** creating dir?), or make it an order-only prerequisite (which means exactly that it never triggers rebuilding of its target).

> I had idea that mtime of the $(DIR) changes, may be it's changing after each "make" run. I checked it with stat, seems it does not change.

But it **can** change. So usually directories are made order-only prerequisites (although it seems irrelevant in this particular case).

Comment: yes, I checked it with "make -d". Something confusing for me is that make check prerequisites of existing dir, but you are right, it's correct because it want to know does `$(DIR)` should be re-making

Comment: @Paul-AG That's how make works: it checks prerequisites to find out if the target should be **rebuilt**. It doesn't matter if target is a directory or a regular file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reason is phony dependency of `$(DIR)`. It will be tested every time and becauseit's phony then it will be re-making. This can be avoided with:

```
define install
commands-of-install...
endef

$(DIR): # no more install dep here
  $(call install)
  another-actions...
```

So `$(DIR)` is just directory without prerequisites, so it will be re-making only it does not exist.